# jquery toggling between heights with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to toggle between two heights on a class and have them animate, I have tried the following:

```
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(){
            $(".section1").toggle(function(){
                             $(".section1").animate({height:"500px"});
                        },function(){
                             $(".section1").animate({height:"0px"});
                        });
            return false;
        });
```

But its not working at all, no animation and the heights do not change.

Here is the CSS for the class

```
.section1{
height: 0px;
}
```

and here is the html

```
<section class="section1">

<!--content here -->
</section>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with simple css and [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('.architectural-films').bind('click', function(){
    $(".section1").toggleClass("toggle");
});
```

```css
.section1{
background:red;
height: 0px;
transition: height 0.25s ease-out;
}
.toggle{
   height: 500px;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section1">

<!--content here -->
</section>
<button class="architectural-films">click me</button>
```

Comment: the ease in is working, the ease out is not working :(

Comment: removing the overflow: visible works, but now not all my content appears.

Comment: `.toggle {
    height: 3000px;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-in;
}`

Comment: Could I use min-height instead?

Comment: Your code ended up working, but I used max-height instead and set it 5000px I just don't understand why, I thought max-height at 5000px would have been massive, but its not, it fits perfectly for some reason.